# How to install libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) on sles11

Tags: linux, rpm, glibc, suse

I cant figure out how do I resolve this issues,
When I'm trying to install   `rpm -i glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc.rpm`

I'm getting conflict errors:

```
warning: glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 3dbdc284
    package glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc is intended for a ppc architecture
    file /lib64/libBrokenLocale.so.1 from install of glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc conflicts with file from package glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64
    file /lib64/libSegFault.so from install of glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc conflicts with file from package glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64
    file /lib64/libanl.so.1 from install of glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc conflicts with file from package glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64
    file /lib64/libc.so.6 from install of glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc conflicts with file from package glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64
    file /lib64/libcidn.so.1 from install of glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc conflicts with file from package glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64
    file /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 from install of glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc conflicts with file from package glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64
    file /lib64/libdl.so.2 from install of glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc conflicts with file from package glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64
    file /lib64/libm.so.6 from install of glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc conflicts with file from package glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64
    file /lib64/libnsl.so.1 from install of glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc conflicts with file from package glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64
    file /lib64/libnss_compat.so.2 from install of glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc conflicts with file from package glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64
    file /lib64/libnss_dns.so.2 from install of glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc conflicts with file from package glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64
    file /lib64/libnss_files.so.2 from install of glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc conflicts with file from package glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64
    file /lib64/libnss_hesiod.so.2 from install of glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc conflicts with file from package glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64
    file /lib64/libnss_nis.so.2 from install of glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc conflicts with file from package glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64
    file /lib64/libnss_nisplus.so.2 from install of glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc conflicts with file from package glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64
    file /lib64/libpthread.so.0 from install of glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc conflicts with file from package glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64
    file /lib64/libresolv.so.2 from install of glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc conflicts with file from package glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64
    file /lib64/librt.so.1 from install of glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc conflicts with file from package glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64
    file /lib64/libthread_db-1.0.so from install of glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc conflicts with file from package glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64
    file /lib64/libutil.so.1 from install of glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc conflicts with file from package glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have the wrong rpm; it says clearly:

```
package glibc-64bit-2.17-4.4.1.ppc is intended for a ppc architecture
```

try looking for one on http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3; I found a candidate here:

ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home%3A/bmwiedemann%3A/branches%3A/Base%3A/System/openSUSE_Factory/

there you need to choose your architecture. Check your architecture using the command

```
uname -m
```

Comment: didn't notice that I was using the wrong rpm, but still having the same conflict error after running `rpm -i glibc-2.17-240.6.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: just wondering do I need to uninstall the old package and install the new one?

Comment: no, rpm managment will do that for you normally (since you will update...). If you still have the same problem; you might still be using the wrong rpm. Do you have a 64bit system? what is the output of `uname -m`?

Comment: uname -m outputs X86_64